# If I play Fallout 3 via Steam, will I still be able to obtain Live achievements?

Tags: steam, achievements, fallout-3, games-for-windows-live

Since Steam usually has it's own achievements system and there is no mention of it on the [page of the game](http://store.steampowered.com/app/22300/), is it still possible to obtain Live achievements, or are they not availble in the steam version?

If you still can get them, how do you enable it to get them?

Comment: It's actually not a duplicate, I just voted too early. There are no Steam achievements for Fallout 3 so the question linked does not apply.

Comment: you access GFWL through windows itself, now, if that helps. The client is not functioning anymore, IIRC, but it is integrated into Windows 8+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best guess would be that you can still get Live achievements, that is, if you're logged in to GFWL (Games for Windows Live).

It depends what version of Fallout 3 you have (i.e. if it's the Game of the Year edition). Some people on Steam's forums are [reporting](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1351059) that they haven't been asked to log in to GFWL.

Comment: some instructions on how to do that would be nice, as there is no "login to Games for Windows Live" link visible in Fallout 3 or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can get Live achievements from Fallout 3 when playing it via Steam (it's a Games For Windows Live game).

On the Xbox 360 the title of the game is "Fallout 3".

Source: I have Fallout 3 for PC (Steam).